# Como utilizar recursos do materialize no php com javascript

Tags: php, javascript, css, materialize

é possível utilizar o materialize em um arquivo php junto ao javascript ?
no retorno de uma função php eu quero emitir uma Materialize.toast(); porém não estou conseguindo, já referenciei o arquivo que tem todas chamadas css e do materialize no php e mesmo assim não funcionou, estou tentando fazer da seguinte maneira no arquivo php.

```
<?php include("../head.php"); // chamadas css e materialize

  echo '<script>Materialize.toast(" teste ", 4500, "blue rounded");</script>'
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso com variáveis de sessão.

Arquivo com a sua função:

```
<?php

...
// Inicia a sessão
session_start();
// Define a variável de sessão com o título do alerta
$_SESSION['toast']['title'] = 'Teste';
// Redireciona para a index
header('Location: index.php');
```

index.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ...
?>

...
<script>
    // Verifica se a variável existe
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['toast']['title'])) { ?>
        Materialize.toast(<?= $_SESSION['toast']['title'] ?>)

        // Destrói a variável
        <?php unset($_SESSION['toast']['title']); ?>
    <?php } ?>
</script>
```